# Wifi and notification issues

Tags: wifi, notifications, cellular-data, nokia-lumia-820

I am owner of a Lumia 820 for two years now. I like Windows Phone, but since the 8.1 update I am experiencing issues with the wifi connection and my notifications.

The main thing is that I am not getting most of the notifications (for example from messaging apps like WhatsApp or Telegram). When I sometimes get them, they are like three hours too late.

I am examining this issue for several months now and it does not matter where I am, if I am connected to my WiFi or not or how good my cellular connection is.

The problem needs to be somewhere else. After long researches on the web, I noticed that the option "Keep Wi-Fi on when the screen times out" is missing on my system. There are a lot of users reporting the same, but there are also others who still have it. Some of the ones who are missing it are reporting this option still takes effect on their connection, but now they are simply not able to change it back.

There seems to be no way of changing that behaviour. But other WP users are getting notifications just fine. This issue is really annoying, because messaging is nearly impossible. Is there anything I could try in order to get proper notifications?

Comment: Wifi stays connected while the device is in standby, that's why there is no option in WP8.1. As for delayed notifications, that could be a Whatsapp issue - does it happen with other apps?

Comment: My experience is a different one. When using the WhatsApp web client, it says my phone is not connected when it locks. This does not seem to be a WhatsApp issue, as this happens for all apps that need an internet connection to notify me, for example Facebook, Facebook Messenger or Telegram. And it does not matter where I am, if I got WiFi or not, or if I have a good or bad cellular connection.

Comment: What exact version are you running currently? Have you already tried a hard reset after the last update?

Comment: No, a hard reset would mean a loss of data to me, as it deletes some more-or-less important application data. I would like to hear about some other ways in order to correct that behaviour before trying this (if there are others?)

Answer (score 1):

I am having this issue, (not getting notifications, and not getting them at all) but when I turned off my WIFI on my LUMIA 520, then all the sudden the notifications started working again. I turned WIFI back on (and am connected to my home signal) and the notifications stopped working.

Comment: Okay, so I have WIFI back on and now notifications are working. I think what fixed it is that I now have Wi-Fi Sense turned OFF. Maybe try turning off Wi-Fi Sense (if you have it on that is) and see if that works?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am experiencing the same behaviour when turning WiFi off and back on, but i got WiFi sense off. I think that might be a thing with my router, which kicks off the phone if it is not active or maybe I need to unblock some ports or something like that. I will do research on that, but it is extremely difficult as only a few others seem to have exact this problem.

Comment: No problem. Sorry this didn't work for you. I also did other things while trying to resolve my issue. I'm not sure if they helped. But you might try these if you haven't already:

Comment: 1. Under "Settings" go to "notifications+actions" and go to each app listed and turn off notifications one-by-one. Also uncheck "show notifications in action center". 2. Then turn your phone off, take the battery out and also the microSim card. Reinstall the card, and turn the phone back on. 3. Go back to Settings, notifications and try turning on  the notifications for a single app, see if that works and then try another. -- I'm not sure if this was part of the process that helped me fix my phone, but hopefully it might work for you.